# Best way to split a mixed directory by extentions?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have a directory tree with several file types and I want to split this directory to the same directory structure, with only one File types.

What is the best way?

Example:
befor

```
dir1 -- dir2 foo.jpg
        dir3 foo.mpg
```

after

```
foo_jpg -- dir1 -- dir2 foo.jpg
                   dir3

foo_mpg -- dir1 -- dir2
                   dir3 foo.mpg
```

Comment: Please add an example listing of directories and files and how you think they should finally be organized.

Answer (score 1):

First make two copies of the tree, using hard links for speed and to avoid any significant disk space.

```
mkdir foo_jpg foo_mpg
cp -al dir1 foo_jpg
cp -al dir1 foo_mpg
```

Then remove stuff you don't want from the trees

```
find foo_jpg -type f ! -name '*.jpg' -delete
find foo_mpg -type f ! -name '*.mpg' -delete
```

At this point you have your 2 trees containing the directory structure and only the files requested. Optionally remove your original tree.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

```
rsync --recursive --include='*.jpg' --filter='-! */' '/dir1' '/foo_jpg/'
```

Comment: Assuming you'd repeat that for every possible extension?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the best solution for me and would like to know all the variants.